# Copying Hyperlink from Excel to Powerpoint in a template format

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am trying to copy some data from Excel to PowerPoint in a format. The Data is being copied as a picture to the powerpoint. There is one field in the Data which is a hyperlink, I would like to extract this url and amend the url to the picture so that when we click on the picture it gets redirected to the amended url.

I am able to copy the data from Excel to Powerpoint using the below code, but couldnt find a way to extract url from hyperlink in data and amend the url to the picture being pasted on Powerpoint

```
Sub Generate_RC_All_PPTs()
Dim myFile, Fileselected As String, Path As String, objPPT As Object
Dim ppApp   As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
 ppApp.Presentations.Open 
Filename:="C:\Release_Review\EBU_ReleaseReviewReport.pptx"

Dim j As Long
Worksheets("RC").Select
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 Range("A1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For j = 1 To NumRows - 1
  Worksheets("RC").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.Copy
Worksheets("Release Commit - All Slides").Select

     Range("U1").Select
     'Selection.Paste
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(1)

ppPres.Slides(1).Copy
ppPres.Slides.Paste Index:=ppPres.Slides.Count + 1

Set activeSlide = ppPres.Slides(ppPres.Slides.Count)

activeSlide.Select
'Step 4: Copy the range as a picture
  Sheets("Release Commit - All Slides").Range("A3:Q29").CopyPicture
  DoEvents

'Step 5: Paste the picture
activeSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
 Next
ppApp.Activate

Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Data from excel is being copied in image format to Powerpoint. I would like to amend the url to the picture being copied to the powerpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only have 1 hyperlink, so the following should work. If there's more than 1, you would have to loop through the Hyperlinks collection to get the right one. In the top section where you gathering data from Excel, add:

```
Dim HLink$
HLink$ = ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks(1)
```

Then in the PowerPoint section, add this after activeSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
  .Action = ppActionHyperlink
  .Hyperlink.Address = HLink$
End With
```

Comment: Hi @John Korchok , I tried using the suggested code , I am getting an error "Error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method" in the second part
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
  .Action = ppActionHyperlink
  .Hyperlink.Address = HLink$
End With

Comment: Since I don't have your workbook, I can't debug. The message means that the object cannot accept a hyperlink. Since you're using a straight Paste command, it seems likely the Excel is _not_ being pasted as a picture, but in the default HTML format. That format can accept a hyperlink within the text, but not applied to the containing shape.

Comment: Hi @John Korchok, I managed to do it with the code suggested above with few tweaks in my original code :) Thank you.